# RethinkDB startup error

Tags: rethinkdb, ubuntu-server

After I fixed some weird HD problems at my server I noticed that all the rethinkdb data had been lost, that wasn't a problem because the data wasn't important, but now when I start the rethinkdb service using `sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb restart` it runs into this error:

```
2017-06-19T00:58:21.734419185 0.174516s notice: Running rethinkdb 2.3.5~0xenial (GCC 5.3.1)...
2017-06-19T00:58:21.783052748 0.223140s notice: Running on Linux 4.4.0-79-generic i686
2017-06-19T00:58:21.783317738 0.223398s notice: Loading data from directory /var/lib/rethinkdb/instance1/data
2017-06-19T00:58:22.008209401 0.448290s info: Automatically using cache size of 100 MB
2017-06-19T00:58:22.009815969 0.449896s warn: Cache size does not leave much memory for server and query overhead (available memory: 877 MB).
2017-06-19T00:58:22.010366140 0.450446s warn: Cache size is very low and may impact performance.
2017-06-19T00:58:22.042696622 0.482776s notice: Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
2017-06-19T00:58:22.128827940 0.568909s error: Error in src/btree/reql_specific.cc at line 256:
2017-06-19T00:58:22.129000921 0.569083s error: Unrecognized reql_btree_superblock_t::magic found.
2017-06-19T00:58:22.129123530 0.569204s error: Backtrace:
2017-06-19T00:58:22.703288073 1.143377s error: Mon Jun 19 00:58:22 2017\n\n1 [0x8747198]: backtrace_t::backtrace_t() at ??:?\n2 [0x8747678]: format_backtrace[abi:cxx11](bool) at ??:?\n3 [0x8a208f4]: report_fatal_error(char const*, int, char const*, ...) at ??:?\n4 [0x86deb12]: get_superblock_metainfo(real_superblock_t*, std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > > > >*, cluster_version_t*) at ??:?\n5 [0x85df957]: store_metainfo_manager_t::store_metainfo_manager_t(real_superblock_t*) at ??:?\n6 [0x846edc9]: store_t::store_t(hash_region_t<key_range_t> const&, serializer_t*, cache_balancer_t*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, perfmon_collection_t*, rdb_context_t*, io_backender_t*, base_path_t const&, uuid_u, update_sindexes_t) at ??:?\n7 [0x894745b]: real_multistore_ptr_t::real_multistore_ptr_t(uuid_u const&, serializer_filepath_t const&, scoped_ptr_t<real_branch_history_manager_t>&&, base_path_t const&, io_backender_t*, cache_balancer_t*, rdb_context_t*, perfmon_collection_t*, scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t>&&, std::vector<scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t>, std::allocator<scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t> > >&&, std::map<uuid_u, std::pair<real_multistore_ptr_t*, auto_drainer_t::lock_t>, std::less<uuid_u>, std::allocator<std::pair<uuid_u const, std::pair<real_multistore_ptr_t*, auto_drainer_t::lock_t> > > >*)::{lambda(int)#1}::operator()(int) const at ??:?\n8 [0x89487d4]: callable_action_instance_t<pmap_runner_one_arg_t<real_multistore_ptr_t::real_multistore_ptr_t(uuid_u const&, serializer_filepath_t const&, scoped_ptr_t<real_branch_history_manager_t>&&, base_path_t const&, io_backender_t*, cache_balancer_t*, rdb_context_t*, perfmon_collection_t*, scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t>&&, std::vector<scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t>, std::allocator<scoped_ptr_t<thread_allocation_t> > >&&, std::map<uuid_u, std::pair<real_multistore_ptr_t*, auto_drainer_t::lock_t>, std::less<uuid_u>, std::allocator<std::pair<uuid_u const, std::pair<real_multistore_ptr_t*, auto_drainer_t::lock_t> > > >*)::{lambda(int)#1}, long long> >::run_action() at ??:?\n9 [0x864f4bd]: coro_t::run() at ??:?
2017-06-19T00:58:22.703737641 1.143820s error: Exiting.
```

Also, it works if I start it using the normal command (`rethinkdb --bind all`), the error only happens with the proccess.